# Is this an Xcode 9 GM bug? Images "Add to target" checkbox don't actually work

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

When adding an image to my project, Xcode shows the check box "Add to target". Even if I enable it, the image doesn't actually get added to the target and the image doesn't show in the app.

When I click on the image and then look at the "File Inspector" on the right pane, I can see the "Target membership" stays unchecked. If I enable it here now, then it works fine and shows in the app.

Shouldn't the "add to target" mean it should enable the "Target membership" automatically?

Comment: I guess so. I faced this too. Had to manually check in the file inspector.

Comment: Yes, it's a bug.

Answer (score 1):

It is XCode 9 bug.

Opened Radar: https://openradar.appspot.com/33577678

Comment: Thanks, will wait for regular version.